# Jupyter plot does not have a scale

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pythonplotter

The X axis and Y axis scale does not appear in plots.
I even tried running exact code from notebooks that have scaled plots.
It appears the problem lies with the notebook and not the code.
[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Jse.png)

Comment: Are you using a dark theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find the problem is more along the lines of what SUJITKUMAR SINGH was suggesting. That is, the problem is not with the notebook itself but using a dark theme for the notebook.

In other words, black print doesn't show well on a black background. But let's say you really love that dark theme. Fortunately, you can change the spines (the individual bounding lines that make up the box), the axis colors (yours didn't have axis labels) and the tick colors. All of them, and individually.

```
# modify your code with this as a quick test show it's the color, not the notebook

plt.rc('axes',edgecolor='xkcd:sky blue')

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 11)
y = x **2
plt.plot(x,y)



# taking it one step further, let's change everything but the y-axis color
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(range(10))
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis title')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis title')

ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('green')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('#0d3f0f')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('m')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('xkcd:sky blue')

ax.xaxis.label.set_color('orange')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('purple')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='blue')

plt.show()
```

that displays (granted on a white background) as:

[image]